# Laravel Set Error Delimiters?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Does Laravel 4 have an equivalent of CodeIgniter's

```
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters()
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, Laravel comes with a validator and the markup is exactly where it should be: in the view.

http://laravel.com/docs/validation#error-messages-and-views

Update:

Although I advise against it the MessageBag actually has a format property, which could be used to store the delimiters.

```
$validator = Validator::make( //...

if($validator->fails())
{
    $validator->getMessageBag()->setFormat('<p class="error">:message</p>');
}
```

The MessageBag can only be accessed, after the data has been validated. Make sure to run passes() or fails() before you do so.

Comment: Precisely. This is something that should be in the view (in general, in an `@include` you can share between different views).

Comment: Good to know. Thanks. Pedanticism aside, setting $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters(<span class="error">) feels more efficient than wrapping each $errors->first() in a span class. Just sayin'.

Comment: @suncoastkid Do that with a view you include.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a validator: http://laravel.com/docs/validation